# How to overcome this error in overlaf latex "Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence"

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.239 �.
        ~yıldırım, P.~Pławiak, R.~S. Tan, U.~R. Acharya, Arrhythmia dete...

The document does not appear to be in UTF-8 encoding.
Try adding \UseRawInputEncoding as the first line of the file
or specify an encoding such as \usepackage [latin1]{inputenc}
in the document preamble.
Alternatively, save the file in UTF-8 using your editor or another tool

Comment: If you want to get an actual answer, we will need a [minimal working example including the bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) to see what is actually causing this, but it looks like a name starts with a non-ASCII character and the system responsible for building the initials does not handle Unicode correctly.

Comment: Don't use `\usepackage[utf-8]{inputenc}` in XeLaTeX

Comment: It just won't work

Comment: May be a badly coded `Ö` (see https://www.pubfacts.com/detail/30245122/Arrhythmia-detection-using-deep-convolutional-neural-network-with-long-duration-ECG-signals)...